# Python Pandas nested calculation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to find the ratio of retailer-sku sales per week across sku.

So far I've tried to group the Retail-Sku data as follows :

```
df_group = df_period.groupby(['Sku', 'Week','RetailerCode'], as_index=False)['Sales'].sum()
```

Result

```
       Sku                   Week                  RetailerCode             Sales
0     SK1234                201649                   RC1001                  0.0
1     SK1234                201649                   RC1003                832.0
2     SK1234                201649                   RC1005                 0.0
3     SK1234                201649                   RC1006                504.0
4     SK1234                201649                   RC1009                  0.0
```

But I'm not being able to find the ratio of sales per week for sales-retailer

Total Sales for week 49 is = 0 + 832 + 0 + 504 + 0 = 1336.

So, for Retailer RC1001 it will be 0/1336, RC1003: 832/1003

I'm bit lost how to group by week & retailer and keep both of them for calculation.

Comment: I'm getting Nan

Comment: There was typo, what about answer?

Comment: Thanks @jezrael  I will read up on transform, as I'm not clear how it is used :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df_group = df.groupby(['Sku', 'Week','RetailerCode'], as_index=False)['Sales'].sum()
sums = df_group.groupby(['Sku', 'Week'])['Sales'].transform('sum')
df_group['rates'] =df_group['Sales'].div(sums)
print (df_group)
      Sku    Week RetailerCode  Sales     rates
0  SK1234  201649       RC1001    0.0  0.000000
1  SK1234  201649       RC1003  832.0  0.622754
2  SK1234  201649       RC1005    0.0  0.000000
3  SK1234  201649       RC1006  504.0  0.377246
4  SK1234  201649       RC1009    0.0  0.000000
```

**Detail**:

```
print (sums)
0    1336.0
1    1336.0
2    1336.0
3    1336.0
4    1336.0
Name: Sales, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I need to sum the sales at sku-week level then divide, can I modify the df_group['Sales'] to  df_group['Sku', 'Week']['Sales].sum() ?

Comment: @user6083088 - need transfrom for same length Series as original `DataFrame`, if use `df_group['Sku', 'Week']['Sales].sum()` it aggregate only.